# Is it possible to extend UIButton so they all have a default behaviour without using @IBActions for each?

Tags: swift, uibutton, ibaction

This may be a silly question, but I'm trying to wrap my head around whether there's a better way to do this. If I have 10 ViewControllers each with a different button (let's say the buttons have Segues created in the Storyboard), but I want all of them to have a simple effect when tapped, I would write something like this:

First, an extension for UIButton so it has a method that handles the animation

```
extension UIButton {
    func tap(){
    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.05, 
                     animations: { self.alpha -= 0.1 },
                     completion: { finish in
                        UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                            self.alpha += 0.1
                     })
    })
}
```

And then an IBAction for every single ViewController.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        button.tap()
    }
}

...

class TenthViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        button.tap()
    }    
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way. Some way to extend UIButton in a way that all UIButtons call tap(). Would I need to add a target to all of them? Would that be override by an @IBAction later on if I do use one?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to make subclass instead of extension. For example if I want to have a few buttons, which change alpha or scale on touch, I use something like this:

```
class CustomButton: UIControl {

   override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.titleLabel.alpha = self.isHighlighted ? 0.3 : 1
            self.transform = self.isHighlighted ? .init(scaleX: 0.98, y: 0.98) : .identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

You can specify that effect in `isHighlighted`. You can make subclass of UIButton or use UIControl – so you can add custom title label, imageView etc. It depends on your usecase:)

Comment: This is amazing, it achieves exactly what I was after with much less code. Thanks a lot @Ondřej. One question though, did you use UIControl instead of UIButton so other types can subclass this too?

Comment: Great, glad to hear that!
Well, in my case I've used UIControl jsut because I wanted to make more complicated view with subviews. (two ImageViews, label..)

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass `UIButton` and add a custom behaviour:

```
//  MARK: Selection Animated Button
/**
A button which animates when tapped.
*/
open class AnimatedButton: UIButton {
    override public var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get { super.isHighlighted }

        set {
            if newValue && !isHighlighted {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05,
                               animations: { self.alpha = 0.5 },
                                 completion: { finish in
                                    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                                        self.alpha = 1.0
                                    })
                })
            }
            super.isHighlighted = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer James. This solution has the benefit of only playing once, which is useful in other situations, however in this case I would need to button to keep its style for as long as the user presses it, so I've accepted the other answer.